# I am healthy like a fish or as a fish?

Tags: word-usage

Which one is the correct way of saying?

I am healthy **like** a fish or **as** a fish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am **as** healthy **as** a fish.
*(assuming a fish is healthy)*

Comment: That's usually the way such idioms as stated (_stubborn as a mule, strong as an ox, hungry as a bear_); however, _healthy like a fish_ wouldn't be grammatically incorrect, and it would have pretty much the same meaning (assuming fish are regarded to be healthy in general).